# how to select the first few elements of product of two matrices and store it to another matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

A----is 3*1 matrix
B----is 4*4 matrix
C----is 3*1 matrix
the formuale is [A;1]=B*[C;1] from this A needs to be extracted.That is add a row of 1 to matrix C. Then extract the first 3 elements of B*C and store it to matrix A.
what i tried was
`A = B*[C;1]([0 1 2])`------did not work.
cannot use any other matrices other than A,B and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing starts with `1` in matlab, the first three elements are `[1,2,3]` or `[1:3]`. You also need to split this into two lines:

```
t = B*[C;1]
A=t(1:3)
```

Comment: is it possible to write the code in one line? only using A,B,C?

Comment: @Daniel What about `B(1:3,:)`?

Comment: @beaker: Don't know what that means. How should this solve the question?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry... `A = B(1:3,:)*[C;1]`